# Decode UTF-16 LE with BOM from ByteArray in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, byte-order-mark, id3, id3v2

I have to extract ID3v2 tags from an MP3 and read [the specification](https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_frame_overview). My C# code in general works fine, but I've got a little problem with the text encoding of the tags.

For example, let's take the `COMM` tag. After the 10 bytes header, the actual text starts with a text encoding byte. Its value is `0x01`. So, the following text is UTF-16 LE with a BOM of `0xFFFE`. Then the text follows, each character as a two byte representation. My code determines that the decoding is UTF-16 and uses

```
encoding.Unicode.GetString(_buffer, startpos, length of bytes);
```

The result is the correct string, but at the beginning, I find [a symbol/character U+FFFE, which represents the BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). I wonder why this remains in the decoded string and I have to remove it afterwards.

I already checked the [MSDN article for `UnicodeEncoding()` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding?view=net-6.0) and tested the sample code, where a string with some Unicode characters will be encoded and written together with a preamble into a text file. This textfile will afterwards be opened again, the string will be decoded and the result is just the text, without the BOM character.
I suspect the difference is that my code gets the tags from a `ByteArray`, while the MS sample code gets it from a text file.
However, the text looks the same, when I open it with a hex editor.

My question:
Why does the BOM character remain in the decoded string when I decode it from a `ByteArray`?

Comment: Because it was put in the data before the data was Encoded.  BOM is probably indicating it is the beginning of the data.

Comment: Hello all and many thanks for the quick response!

Comment: No, `0x01` only indicates "Unicode" (implying UTF-16, but strictly also UCS-2) but not any byte order - that's the reason why a BOM should be used/expected for the actual byte order of the text. Respect it, then just cut off the first 2 bytes if they're a BOM.